# python source code for "radians"

Tags: python, open-source, radians

I need to match the implementation of my c code for `x*pi/180.00`, where x is in degrees, to that of Python's `radians(x)`.  I would like to see Python's source code for the **radians** function. I have tried both

```
print inspect.getsource(type(radians))
```

and

```
print getsource(radians)
```

with no success. Any thoughts?

Comment: The Python Standard Library code is on github, which library/module are you referring to?

Comment: I think it is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L2187)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(3.14159265358979323846/180.0)

180.0/3.14159265358979323846

Answer (score 2):

From the CPython source code (not in contiguous order)

```
static const double degToRad = Py_MATH_PI / 180.0;
static const double radToDeg = 180.0 / Py_MATH_PI;

/*[clinic input]
math.radians
    x: double
    /
Convert angle x from degrees to radians.
[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
math_radians_impl(PyObject *module, double x)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=34daa47caf9b1590 input=91626fc489fe3d63]*/
{
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(x * degToRad);
}
```

Your problem with the **inspect** package is that it works only on Python objects, not the underlying implementation code.

Answer (score 0):

`inspect` can only fetch source code from modules written in python.  Modules written in C (e.g. `math`) do not have the sources available.  With that said, the official source code for CPython is on github.  `math.radians` lives in [`Modules/mathmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L2187) and the implementation is really simple (multiply a float by a constant scale factor).